# How do I print this JavaScript data structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a trouble with for loop, I am just trying to print out the detail array in the data structure.

```
  for(i in myObj.detail){
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].bigtitle + "</h2>";  

  for(z=0; z<3; z++){   
     x+="<h2>"+ myObj.detail[i].infor[i].step[z] + "</h2>"; 
     for(m=0; m<3; m++){

       x+="<h2>"+ myObj.detail[i].infor[i].image[m] + "</h2>"; 

         for(c=0; c<3; c++){

            x+="<h2>"+ myObj.detail[i].infor[i].content[c] + "</h2>"; 
           }
        }
     }
 }  



myObj={"detail":[{
         "bigtitle":"Print Room",
         "lable":3,        
         "infor":[{"step":["First","Second","Third"]},
                  {"image":["imge-1","imge-2","image-3"]},
                  {"content":["1111","2222","3333"]}
                 ]}
               }
```

the result should look like this:

```
Print Room 

  First
  image-1
  1111
  Second
  imge-2
  2222
  Third
  image-3
  3333
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use all these loops, they seem to be useless and will lead to many Exceptions, you just need `2` loops:

- First to loop over `myObj.detail` using `myObj.detail.length` to loop over all this array elements.
- And second one to loop over `step`, `image` and `content` entries, use a for loop with a fixed counter to get all these `3` entries.

So your code will look something like this:

```
var x = "";
for (i in myObj.detail) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].bigtitle + "</h2>";
    for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[0].step[m] + "</h2>";
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[1].image[m] + "</h2>";
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[2].content[m] + "</h2>";
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
myObj = {
  detail: [{
    bigtitle: "Print Room",
    lable: 3,
    infor: [{
        step: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
      },
      {
        image: ["imge-1", "imge-2", "image-3"]
      },
      {
        content: ["1111", "2222", "3333"]
      }
    ]
  }]
}

var x = "";
for (i in myObj.detail) {
  x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].bigtitle + "</h2>";
    for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[0].step[m] + "</h2>";
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[1].image[m] + "</h2>";
      x += "<h2>" + myObj.detail[i].infor[2].content[m] + "</h2>";
    }
}

document.write(x);
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you. This question took me for a long time ：）

Comment: @Toney You are welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try without loop cos this json is simple to access and good for manage cpu :) here the example :

```
console.log(myObj.detail[0].bigtitle);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].lable);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[0].step[0]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[0].step[1]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[0].step[2]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[1].image[0]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[1].image[1]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[1].image[2]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[2].content[0]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[2].content[1]);
console.log(myObj.detail[0].infor[2].content[2]);
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/RLPLjd?editors=1111

Comment: thank you for helping me, thank you for giving a suggestion! :)